# what is the definition of the space $C([0,T];H^s)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the definition of the space $C([0,T];H^s)$?

Here, we are considering the solutions of a PDE, and $H^s$ is the Sobolev space.

My book says we are assuming that a solution lies in this space, without defining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, if $Y$ is a normed space then, $C([0,T];Y)$ is the space of all continuous functions $f:[0,T]\to Y$. It is a normed space with norm given by $$\|f\|=\sup\{\|f(x)\|_Y:\ x\in [0,T]\}$$

where $\|\cdot\|_Y$ is the norm of $Y$.